# Occasional "Error: socket hang up" in node.js when using https.request

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have this code that makes a POST request to the remote API.

```
var method = 'POST';
var params = {foo: 'bar', /* something else */};
var path = '/method/somemethod';
var host = 'my.host.com';
var body = querystring.stringify(params);

var options = {
  host: host,
  port: 443,
  path: path,
  method: method,
  agent: false
};

var req = https.request(options);

req.on('response', function(res) {
  var chunks = [];
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    var data = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf-8');
    // done
  });
});

if (method == 'POST') {
  req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
  req.setHeader('Content-Length', Buffer.byteLength(body));
  req.end(body);
} else {
  req.end();
}

req.on('error', function(e) {
  log('error:', e);
});
```

Most of the time it works fine, but SOMETIMES socket hangs up.

(Btw, it also happens to GET requests.)

I am sure there's no problem with my internet connection or the remote server. I tried to make this request using other tools/languages, and everything works OK, only node.js occasionally hangs up.

Node.js version is 4.1.1.

Usually my app making a few simultaneous requests, if that matters (ie, not just a single request, but two asynchronous. I have no idea how it can affect my problem, I'm just out of theories about what may be wrong. Or maybe SSL handshake failing at some point?).

I've seen another threads with similar complains but they either did not help me or not relevant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.